# Why do AWS SES Sent Emails don't show up?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses, email-validation, email-client

I am new to AWS and am using the AWS Simple Email Service. For the first time I sent a bulk email from my site to about 32 people on 14th Dec. I used all the SMTP credentials provided by AWS.

However as of now, my dashboard shows 14 emails sent from 14th dec (18.30) to 15th dec (18.30) UTC time.

I want to know 1) do the emails not go together or the system queues them on it's own 2) Should I assume the remaining emails are lost or wait for the dashboard to refresh. Is it possible that emails can take 2 to 3 days to reach the recipient's inbox?

I want to understand how thing works and how I can track that all emails are delivered to the recipient's inbox.

Comment: In SES dashboard on the Left side in Configuration sub menu select Suppression List. There you may see if any email ID is blocked or had a bounce.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the AWS Docs here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/request-production-access.html

It states:

***To help prevent fraud and abuse, and to help protect your reputation as a sender, we apply certain restrictions to new Amazon SES accounts.***

You have to be out of the SES sandbox to send emails to non-validated email recipients. Have you done this?

Comment: Yes I am out of the sandbox.